# Resolve Class revtex4-2 Error: The cite package cannot be used with revtex4-2 error

Tags: bibliographies, revtex, journal-publishing, journal, cite-package

My MWE called texfile.tex is:

```
% Paper template
\documentclass[reprint,aps,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts]{revtex4-2}

%%% External packages
\usepackage{graphicx,bm,xspace,dcolumn,mcite}

%%% Document settings if required
%\include{common-defs} 

% define page size
\setlength{\textheight}{235mm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{6mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{15mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{163mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1mm}

% width of abstract
\newlength{\abstwidth}
\setlength{\abstwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\abstwidth}{-25mm}

% allow figure and text to better coexist on same page
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\circ$}

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}
% set sloppy attitude to line breaks
\sloppy

\pagestyle{empty}

\headnote{
    \begin{flushright}
        \small{Preprint no:\\}
        \hspace{-2cm}
    \end{flushright}
}

\title{paper title}
\author{author1, author2} 
\email[autho.r1@email]{autho.r1@email}
\affiliation{Institute}

\abstract{Some text here }


\textit{Introduction} -more text and we cite this reference \cite{author:2022now}. 

\biblipgraphy{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

I have revtex4-2.cls, revsymb4-2.sty and aps4-2.rtx files in the root directory. I am using ubuntu 20.04. I get the error with `pdflatex texfile.tex` that  `Class revtex4-2 Error: The cite package cannot be used with revtex4-2`. I have also tried to compile it with the references listed as `\bibitem{}` instead of an external .bib file (which is not my favourite and would like to keep the .bib file), which did not resolve the problem. The bibfile has a `author:2022now` entry though of the type

```
@article{ParticleDataGroup:2012pjm,
    author = "Beringer, J. and others",
    collaboration = "Particle Data Group",
    title = "{Review of Particle Physics (RPP)}",
    reportNumber = "SLAC-REPRINT-2014-001",
    doi = "10.1103/PhysRevD.86.010001",
    journal = "Phys. Rev. D",
    volume = "86",
    pages = "010001",
    year = "2012"
}
```

How I can compile the document without these errors? I have checked some older posts on this issue, but that did not help.

Comment: We can't compile your document as we don't have access to the file `common-defs.tex`.

Comment: I have now commented it out - it is not required for the given MWE. The bibfile has a ```author:2022now``` entry though of the type ```@article{ParticleDataGroup:2012pjm,
    author = "Beringer, J. and others",
    collaboration = "Particle Data Group",
    title = "{Review of Particle Physics (RPP)}",
    reportNumber = "SLAC-REPRINT-2014-001",
    doi = "10.1103/PhysRevD.86.010001",
    journal = "Phys. Rev. D",
    volume = "86",
    pages = "010001",
    year = "2012"
}```

Comment: Please update your question with that information, comments are not meant to hold data

Comment: @daleif did now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling I find in the logs

```
! Class revtex4-2 Error: The mcite package cannot be used with revtex4-2.

See the revtex4-2 class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.29 \begin{document}
                     
I cannot continue. You must remove the \usepackage\ statement that caused that package to be loaded.
```

which seems self-explanatory, the features of `mcite` are provided (not necessarily in an identical manner) by `revtex`/`natbib` so `\usepackage{mcite}` can readily be removed.

Making a few other changes with the help of the log file:

Correcting a typo in`\bibiography`

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.52 \biblipgraphy
                  {bibfile}
```

removing the use of `\headnote` which seems to be undefined (possibly from `common-defs.tex`?)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.35 \headnote
              {
```

and replacing the citation with the `ParticleDataGroup:20212pjm` supplied.

The final error is unfortunately a bit more cryptic, though just as easy a fix

```
! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.
\enddocument ...cument/end}\deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.53 \end{document}
```

In revtex the abstract is an environment and so used as `\abstract{Foo}`, latex gets lost looking for `\end{abstract}`, the correct usage is

```
\begin{abstract}
Some text here
\end{abstract}
```

With which this now compiles, however the title matter is missing as this is typeset by `\maketitle` which should be inserted after the `abstract` environment.